# Angular 9 - ngModel select and array of objects (inside a ngFor loop)

Tags: select, ngfor, ngmodel

I have an array of objects

```
private data=[{title:'a',num:10},{title:'b',num:20},{title:'c',num:30}];
```

and I want, for each of the objects to create a select box that modifies it's num field

```
<form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()'>
  {{ data | json }}
  <div *ngFor="let item of data;let i=index">
    <div>{{ data[i]['title'] }}</div>
    <select [(ngModel)]="data[i]['num']">
        <option [ngValue]="10">10</option>
        <option [ngValue]="20">20</option>
        <option [ngValue]="30">30</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  ...
```

**IF THE CODE IS INSIDE A FORM, then the data is NEVER updated and all select box start empty**

thanks

[image]

Comment: let me know if my answer works for you

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing a private property in your template, it has to be public.

Component

```
public data=[{title:'a',num:10},{title:'b',num:20},{title:'c',num:30}];
```

Template

```
{{ data | json }}
<div *ngFor="let item of data;">
    <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
    <select [(ngModel)]="item.num">
        <option [ngValue]="10">10</option>
        <option [ngValue]="20">20</option>
        <option [ngValue]="30">30</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Working example :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nazzvh?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @phil123456 well it's weird because on my Stackblitz example it's clearly working ... you select a value and the printed JSON above is updated ... what browser are you using ?

Comment: it works on the stackblitz for me, but not in my app, weird indeed, I've pasted my package.json in the questions...I guess I will have to recreate a project with angular 10 :-( ...updating to 10 is quiet nightmarish

Comment: @phil123456 try to isolate your code step by step until your find why this is not working. Did you specified explicitly that the property is public ? And the source of the property isn't read-only or something like that ? Or re-instantiated by another service or what so ever ?

Comment: I updated the question, it stops working once I put the template code in a <form>

Comment: I changed form->div, I dont need forms anyway

Comment: @phil123456 Yeah that's normal behavior. If you put a <form> around then you should use the model of this form, maybe you don't need the <form> tag after all ?  https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: @phil123456 I see you managed to make it work .... feel free to upvote if I helped

Answer (score 0):

apparently, forms and angular still dont go well together

I changed  to  and it works like a charm

```
<form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()'>
  {{ data | json }}
  <div *ngFor="let item of data;let i=index">
    <div>{{ data[i]['title'] }}</div>
    <select [(ngModel)]="data[i]['num']">
        <option [ngValue]="10">10</option>
        <option [ngValue]="20">20</option>
        <option [ngValue]="30">30</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```